# Handling page requests in MVC

Tags: php, mvc

Is this an efficient way to handle page requests in MVC?

index.php:

```
require 'Classes/Autoloader.php';
Autoloader::start();
Session::start();

new Bootstrap();
```

Bootstrap.php

```
class Bootstrap {
    private $controller = null,
            $action = null,
            $args = null;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->manage_url();
        if($this->page_exist()){
            $this->request();
        } else {
            $error = new ErrorController();
            $error->error404();
        }
    }

    private function request(){
        $controller = new $this->controller();
        if(!$this->args){ $controller->{$this->action}(); }
        else{
           $count_args = count($this->args);
           switch ($count_args) {
               case 1:
                   $controller->{$this->action}($this->args[0]);
                   break;
               case 2:
                   $controller->{$this->action}($this->args[0], $this->args[1]);
                   break;
               case 3:
                   $controller->{$this->action}($this->args[0], $this->args[1], $this->args[2]);
                   break;
               case 4:
                   $controller->{$this->action}($this->args[0], $this->args[1], $this->args[2], $this->args[3]);
                   break;
           }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get controller, action and parametes
     */
    private function manage_url(){
        $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $uri = trim($uri, '/');
        $this->remove_query_or_hash($uri);
        $exploded_uri = explode('/', $uri);
        $this->controller = Util::istruthy_or($exploded_uri[0], 'Main').'Controller';
        $this->action = Util::istruthy_or($exploded_uri[1], 'index');
        $this->args = array_slice($exploded_uri, 2);
    }

    private function remove_query_or_hash(&$uri){
        $query = strpos($uri, '?');
        $hash = strpos($uri, '#');
        if($query!==FALSE||$hash!==FALSE){
            $idx =  $query < $hash ? $hash : $query;
            $uri = substr($uri, 0, $idx);
        }
    }

    private function page_exist(){
        $controller = class_exists($this->controller);
        $method = method_exists($this->controller, $this->action);
        if(!$controller||!$method){
            return FALSE;
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Util istruthy_or():

```
public static function istruthy_or(&$var, $val = NULL){
    return isset($val) ? ($var ? $var : $val) : ($var ? $var : NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is great as long as you are the only one working with this code and all your uri ideally resolve to `/controller/action/args`. Problems will start when your client asks for a friendly uri like `/my-section/my-page` or someone else will have to maintain your code.

To address the problem with uri you might need custom routing (rules for non-standard uri routing that apply *before* the standard `/controller/action/args`). For examples of such rules you should check how it's done in different frameworks and find the one that fits your liking. Here's how it's done in [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html).

Second issue is a bit less clear. By looking at your code:

```
Autoloader::start();
Session::start();
new Bootstrap();
```

One will never realise where exactly is the job gets done. You could do it a lot clearer by chaning, for example, to this:

```
$bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
$bootstrap->process_request($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

But that's not the only issue. Next you call `manage_url()`, which does not get any paramteter and therefore is untestable. You could make it testable by calling it with a parameter `manage_url($uri)` - this way you can call it in a test with different uris and see how it handles it's job. Then again, what is it's job? It does multiple things, thats why such a non-telling name.

You could make your code a lot more clear for future developers (including yourself) by making each function do one task. For example:

```
public function process_request($uri)
{

    // first you want a function to clear uri from unwanted parts
    $uri = $this->prepare_uri($uri); 

    // then you want to apply custom routing I described earlier
    if (!$this->apply_custom_routing($uri)) {

        // if none matched, apply default routing of your manage_url()'s last part
        if (!$this->apply_default_routing($uri)) {

            // none valid routing found - 404
            $this->apply_error_routing();
        }
    }

    // now you know request details and can proceed
    $this->call_controller();

}
```

Note that it's now pretty clear what each function does and each of them is at least somewhat testable, because their dependencies are clear.

Also note, that you don't need that ugly `switch` statement in `request()`. There is a function for that type of situations (when you don't know amount of arguments beforehand):

```
call_user_func_array(array($this->controller, $this->action), $this->args);
```

Answer (score 3):

MVC is a concept that stems from good OOP practices. It's about seperating your application to three different parts: **Input<sub>Controllers</sub>, Processing<sub>Model</sub> and Output<sub>View</sub>**.

What you are describing is the bootstrap page, which, at least from my perspective **should not be a class**.

Here's my approach to this:

#### index.php

```
<?php
require "../bootstrap.php";
```

#### bootstrap.php

```
<?php
//Pseudo-code ahead:
require autoloader;
start router;
add router rules (either from file, or actually in the code)
$route = $router->route($uri); //$route is a Route object which tells us 
                               //what controller to use, what are the parameters, etc.
$controllerClass = $route->getControllerClass();
$controllerAction = $route->getControllerAction();
$controller = new $controllerClass($request); 
//Where $request is the Request object, containing the URI, GET, POST, COOKIES, etc.
$viewParams = call_user_func_array([$controller, $controllerAction], $route->getParameters());
//$route->getParameters() is an array of parameters from the route.
//call_user_func_array will transform that array into actual arguments to pass in.

$viewClass = $viewParams["class"];
$viewAction = $viewParams["action"];
$view = new $viewClass($request);
echo $view->render($viewParams);
```